# Flutter : Avoid using `forEach` with a function literal

Tags: flutter, dart

Hi everyone this is my whole method :

```
Future<void> init() async {
    FirebaseAuth.instance.userChanges().listen((user) {
      if (user != null) {
        _loginState = ApplicationLoginState.loggedIn;
        _guestBookSubscription = FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('guestbook')
            .orderBy('timestamp', descending: true)
            .limit(3)
            .snapshots()
            .listen((snapshot) {
          _guestBookMessages = [];
          snapshot.docs.forEach((document) {
            _guestBookMessages.add(
              GuestBookMessage(
                name: document.data()['name'] as String,
                message: document.data()['text'] as String,
              ),
            );
          });
          notifyListeners();
        });
      } else {
        _loginState = ApplicationLoginState.loggedOut;
        _guestBookMessages = [];
        _guestBookSubscription?.cancel();
      }
      notifyListeners();
    });
  }
```

the part that dart complains about is this one :

```
snapshot.docs.forEach((document) {
            _guestBookMessages.add(
              GuestBookMessage(
                name: document.data()['name'] as String,
                message: document.data()['text'] as String,
              ),
            );
          });
```

how can I change this method without ruining the whole functionality ?
Im just looking for a way that makes dart happy .
I appreciate your help in advance.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

AVOID using forEach with a function literal.

**AVOID:**

```
snapshot.docs.forEach((document) {
  ...
});
```

**GOOD:**

```
for (var document in snapshot.docs) {
  // Rest of your code
}
```

Comment: @BugsHappen probably because it will make the code look way more complex. It is recommended to either do like Sifat proposed above, or I think even better is to create another function that you will supply to `forEach` method. It is described here: [link](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/usage#avoid-using-iterableforeach-with-a-function-literal) Quote:  "If you want to invoke some already existing function on each element, forEach() is fine." So define a new function and use it in `forEach`.

Comment: Could you explain why either is good/bad?

Comment: Agreed, the "good/bad" terminology is unhelpful.  I think that in most languages it is more performant to use a loop rather than call an anonymous function repeatedly.  This is because functions come with the overhead of allocating and cleaning up a stack, whereas a loop gets optimized into more "flat" code by the compiler.  I assume that is the case here as well, and why Dart issues a warning.

Comment: It is ridiculous tbh. They should improve their compiler/interpreter instead of giving such recommendations.

Comment: The latter is less readable in my opinion

Comment: "Bad" and "Good" with just the reproduction of the two options not seems a good answer when the question is about an error that tells "Avoid". In this sense, the answer below is more detailed about this case.

Answer (score 5):

Using like `data.forEach(function);`
example:

```
void main() async {
  List<int> list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

  //recommended
  list.forEach(showSquareNumbers);

  //not recommended
  list.forEach((int number) => showSquareNumbers(number));
  list.forEach((int number) {
    showSquareNumbers(number);
  });
}

void showSquareNumbers(int data) {
  print("$data * $data = ${data * data}");
}
```

**This is my opinion.**

I think the `forEach` seems more complicated than the `for` loop and the `forEach` can't use `continue` and `break` (`return` is available but not a thing happens when using `return`).

```
void test(List data) {
  data.forEach((element) {
    print(element);
    if(element) return;
  });

  for (var element in data) {
    print(element);
    if(element) continue;
    if(element) break;
    if(element) return;
  }
}
```

I think we should use the `for` instead of the `forEach` loop when your `forEach` loop seems like this code below because the `for` loop have many options more than `forEach` as I said.

```
  data.forEach((element) {
    print(element)
  });
  //or
  data.forEach((element) => print(element));
```

I think the `forEach` loop is used for short code (easy to understand) and when you want to do something you don't care about the result like this code (using with `Function(dynamic)`).

```
void test(List data) {
  void showInTerminal(e) {
    print("data is $e");
  }
  data.forEach(showInTerminal);
  
  Function(dynamic) function = showInTerminal;
  data.forEach(function);
}
```

Make sure the data type and function(type) are the same.

```
//error
void test(List<Map> data) {
  void showInTerminal(String e) {
    print("data is $e");
  }
  data.forEach(showInTerminal);
}

//success
void test(List<Map> data) {
  void showInTerminal(Map e) {
    print("data is $e");
  }
  data.forEach(showInTerminal);
}
```

I code like this. I think it's easy to read.

```
void test() {
  dataList.forEach(removeData);
  fileList.forEach(removeFile);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a debate below the accepted answer, about readability of the recommended lint rules at stake here.
This is the rule in question causing the problem : https://dart.dev/tools/linter-rules/avoid_function_literals_in_foreach_calls

You can disable it by modifying your analysis_options.yaml file :

```
linter:
  rules:
    avoid_function_literals_in_foreach_calls: false
```

Answer (score -5):

Use `await for`:

```dart
await for (final document in snapshot.docs) {
  // Your code...
}
```

Comment: thanks for your attention . i tried your solution but here the method 'listen' isn't avaliable to use

Comment: @delaram Sorry I mistakenly wrote `.docs` in the code. I've updated it though.